# Query to boost records that are a proper subset of the query or the query is a proper subset of the record?

Tags: elasticsearch

In my domain it is common for a query to  be less specific than the information in the required field of the document, conversely a document could be less specific than the query.  However, if both the query and the record are both relatively specific and don't match then it is a poor quality match in general.

So if someone queries "car" I would be fine with returning "red car."
If someone queries "black car" I would be fine with returning "car."  However, "red car" would be unacceptable for the query "black car."

Is it possible to create a query such that the phrase being matched against documents is a subset of the information in that field of the document and visa versa?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant achieve whats you want with elasticsearch, but you can easily boost specifics documents upon generics ones.

The `minimum_should_match` feature of elasticsearch should help you ( documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-boolean)

If you configure your match query to use for example a minimum_should_match: 3<70%

example :

```
GET <your_index>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "<your_field>" : "red car",
            "minimum_should_match": "3<70%"
        }
    }
}
```

Since the query have less than 4 terms, all will be required so only document with "red car" will match. But then the generic "car" document will no be match. But if you add another query without the `minimum_should_match` in a boolean query, then they will be matched again.

```
GET <your_index>/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "<your_field>" : "red car",
                        "minimum_should_match": "3<70%"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "message" : "red car"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

    }
}
```

With this query for a "red car" query,

"red car" documents will be ranked first since they match the two queries
generic "car" documents and "black car" will come after since they match only one of the two queries.

The only real way to fulfill your need is to add NLP on the user query, to extract colors and use the color as a filter for your query instead of just using in in the textual query. But you will also have to extract color during indexation.

I recommend you to check this processor [elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp) as a starting point

Answer (score 0):

Have you fiddled with Ontologies?

Today these are being used for problems similar to yours.

Ontologies are "Formal representations of a context where world entities are represented by classes which in turn are inter-related - these entities can be instanced" (oversimplified explanation). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science)

Looks a lot like Object Oriented Programming, but is more related to Data modeling approach. You could, for example, have a "Car" Class, and make red and black instances. You can add constraints and query your ontology for this information (if you're a recommender system, you have endpoints linking to red or black car offers, for example).

Of course, there are some formalizations to Ontologies and specific tools (Protégé, OWL, Turtle etc), but you could use any technology, such, as mentioned, ElasticSearch, Graph Database (Neo4j, ArangoDB) etc. You just have to model your data accordingly.

Also, keep in mind that you might have, as stated in other answers, apply Natural Language Processing to the queries in order to retrieve "the class in question" and "the attributes".

These are some ideas you can work with to build a lasting, intelligent, structure.